# callSingle() usage in karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I am using **callSingle()** in karate- config.js file, but in the actual feature that is being called, I am unable to read "**env**" and "**baseURL**" which works fine in regular features. How can I make it work? This is my karate-config.js  and feature.

```
var env = karate.env;
    if (!env) {
        env = 'DEV';
    }    
     if(env === 'DEV') {
                 baseURL = 'http://dev.companyname.com';
                 cleardata = karate.callSingle('classpath:com/cleardata.feature');
             }
     else if(env === 'QA') {
                 baseURL = 'http://qa.companyname.com';
                 cleardata = karate.callSingle('classpath:com/cleardata.feature');
             }


Scenario Outline: 
 Given url baseURL
 When path "/some/path/"+id
 Then method Get
 Then status 200
 And def id = response.id

 Examples:
 |read('classpath:com/'+ env + '_testdata.csv')|
```

I am getting this error:
ERROR com.intuit.karate - evaluation of 'karate-config.js' failed: javascript function call failed: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException:
[1.1:12] cleardata.feature:16 - url not set, please refer to the keyword documentation for 'url'

but if I update my feature like that it works fine:

```
Scenario Outline: 
     Given url 'http://dev.companyname.com'
     When path "/some/path/"+id
     Then method Get
     Then status 200
     And def id = response.id
    
     Examples:
     |read('classpath:com/dev_testdata.csv')|
```

**Thank You**

Comment: you can pass parameters to `karate.callSingle()` also see this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.0.1/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/parallel/karate-config.js